# How to apply pandas style to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have the following dataframe:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','c'],
                 'c2':['aa', 'bb','cc'] })
```

And I have the following function to color cells:

```py
def color_cell(cell, c):
    if cell in c:
        return "background-color: yellow"
    else:
        return ""
```

I want to use this function to color different columns of the dataframe.
For each column there is different `c`.

I try this:

```py
cols=['c1', 'c2']
    
c1=['a']
c2=['aa', 'bb']
c= [c1, c2]
    
for i in range(0, 2):           
    html = (df.style
            .applymap(color_cell, 
                      c=c[i],                       
                      subset = cols[i])
            .render()
           )
(HTML(html))
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because only the result from the last iteration is returned.

What should I do to get all the columns colored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is better to make a list of target elements and pass them on to method parameters than to process them with for loop.

#### Get target list

```py
c1= ['a']
c2= ['aa', 'bb']
c= [c1, c2]

slist = [st for row in c for st in row]
```

*slist: ['a', 'aa', 'bb']*

#### Method

```py
def highlight_cols(s, cells):
    color = 'yellow' if s in cells else 'gray'
    return 'background-color: % s' % color

html = (df.style.applymap(highlight_cols, cells=slist).render())
```

#### Result

```
display(df.style.applymap(highlight_cols, cells=slist))
```

[image]

## ________________

### ▶️ Update

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a','b','c', 'd'],
                 'c2':['a', 'aa', 'bb','cc'] })

# Specifies the style of the dataframe as a variable
df_style = df.style

def color_cell(cell, c):
    if cell in c:
        return "background-color: yellow"
    else:
        return ""

cols=['c1', 'c2']
c1=['a']
c2=['aa', 'bb']
c= [c1, c2]

# Use the newly specified variable 'df_style' instead of 'df.style'
for i in range(0, 2):           
    html = (df_style.applymap(color_cell, c=c[i], subset = cols[i]).render())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this won't work because maybe in the column `c2` there is an `'a'` which I don't want to be colored.

Comment: @Ani I overlooked that there could be equal values. I revised it again, so please check it.